# Tensorflow initialize variable with numpy doesn't work

Tags: variables, numpy, tensorflow, initialization

So I am trying to initialize my variable with some specific weights:

```
W = tf.Variable(np.eye(19) , name = 'Diag')
```

But if i now run this code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(W.eval())
```

I end up with a zeros matrix:

```
 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

I do not understand what is going on since e.g. 
    W = tf.Variable([1,2,3] , name = 'Diag')
preserves the values. What should I do?

I guess the tf.initialize_all_variables() overwrites my values but without it I get the FailedPreconditionError that complains about unitialized variables.

Comment: There is no reason why this shouldn't work - I just tried it and it works as expected (using TF 0.12). Note that when you initialize `W` it has shape (19, 19) but when you print it it has shape (3, 3). Something must be happening between constructing `W` and printing it that you are not showing here ...

Comment: Also, you should use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead of `tf.initialize_all_variables()` as the latter is deprecated (but this shouldn't be the reason for the error)

Comment: You were right, it did indeed work, I simply had to restart my docker container. Sometimes tensorflow does weird things.